# Freemember - Set to not Activation Required AND it automatically sets to Pending. How do I change this?

Tags: members, error, freemember, activation

I've built a site using freemember and although there's "no activation requried" it automatically sets the member to "Pending" rather than "Members".

I've checked my encryption key and turned off terms of service - still no joy!

It's pretty urgent so any help would be awesome :) Thanks

Comment: Please post at least a snippet of your template code so we can see what they problem might be.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set group_id whitelist parameter and group_id form input?
https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/register_tag.md